# phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect: Login not working

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
this.FBlogin = function() {
    console.log("TEST");

    FB.login(
            function(response) {

                console.log(response);

                if (response.session) {
                    console.log(response.session);
                } else {
                    console.log('not logged in');
                }
            },
            { scope: "user_about_me, user_activities, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_interests, user_location, user_religion_politics, user_status, user_website, offline_access, email" }
    );
}
```

Only the TEST is printed in logCat:

```
02-01 00:09:30.616: D/CordovaLog(1489): file:///android_asset/www/js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js: Line 24 : Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully.
02-01 00:09:30.616: I/Web Console(1489): Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully. at file:///android_asset/www/js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js:24
02-01 00:09:32.096: D/DroidGap(1489): onMessage(spinner,stop)
02-01 00:09:33.907: D/(1489): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x93e9038, tid 1526
02-01 00:09:48.106: D/CordovaLog(1489): TEST
02-01 00:09:48.106: D/CordovaLog(1489): file:///android_asset/www/js/auth.js: Line 148 : TEST
02-01 00:09:48.106: I/Web Console(1489): TEST at file:///android_asset/www/js/auth.js:148
02-01 00:09:48.185: D/dalvikvm(1489): GC_CONCURRENT freed 56K, 2% free 10199K/10375K, paused 4ms+3ms
02-01 00:09:48.386: D/DroidGap(1489): Paused the application!
02-01 00:09:48.386: D/CordovaWebView(1489): Handle the pause
02-01 00:09:49.025: I/dalvikvm(1489): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-01 00:09:49.055: I/dalvikvm(1489): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-01 00:09:49.145: W/EGL_emulation(1489): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-01 00:09:49.595: D/OpenGLRenderer(1489): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-01 00:09:55.026: D/DroidGap(1489): Resuming the App
```

It seams that I am redirected to the FB app, but I only see the AppId in the top bar and a kind of alert box which says "facebook". My app is paused and after coming back the success handler is not called? Anyboby know why? Or how to debug?

P.S. The appId is correctly added to strings.xml. A key hash was generated and added to FB, as also package and classname. Did I miss anything?

P.P.S. Using: Phonegap 2.2. and the corresponding branch of the phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect lib: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/cordova-2.2-facebook-android-3.0

Comment: your using the childbrowser plugin to run this?

Comment: No as the title said the pligin no childbrowser hack

Comment: can you add the plugin link to your question

Comment: I'm having issues with this particular branch of the plugin as well on Android but my issue is that when the Facebook app is installed after accepting permissions on the popup I don't receive a valid session back (though do when debugging step by step) is you issue any better without the Facebook app installed?

Comment: The permission dialog isn't poping up at all in my case. Maybe I shouold check the hash tag again, maybe a problem if the OpenSSL Version I use.

Comment: In the master branch is a hint: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/blob/master/README.md using Win7 X64 do not use OpenSSL 0.9.8k. But also using the recommended openssl version, no response from FB app. Anyone a idea how to debug?

Comment: you can filter to output only cordova messages with `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok it seams also to be an issue with the scope. After changing to email only, the success function callback is executed.

```
{ scope: "email" }
```

see also: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/240

Attention the examples are outdated:

```
response.session
```

use the following instead:

```
response.authResponse.accessToken
response.authResponse.session_key
response.authResponse.expiresIn
response.authResponse.userId
response.authResponse.sig
response.authResponse.expirationTime
response.status
```

It the OAuth2 handling: see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/07/21/updated-javascript-sdk-and-oauth-2-0-roadmap/

Comment: Also did a blog entry about the topic: http://pjsdev.blogspot.de/2013/03/phonegap-build-facebook-connect-part-2.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Phonegap Build / Build Facebook Plugin?

Are you calling FB.init() correctly before any other Facebook calls?

Are all of your scopes spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

{ scope: "email" } you have to put in callback otherwise it will not get executed . Here is an working example for this

[facebook connect using cordova cli 3.3](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed all the steps, the login work prefect for the first time.

After login, the application doesnt work and when its relanuched i get the Invaid android_key parameter error.

The Hash keys are configured in the FB App. I am using Phonegap Build 3.0